# Mock log file for unit test in .NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, .net-core, nlog

In my C# application I have a `getLogFile` which is set by calling the `GetLogFile()` method:

```
private static string getLogFile = GetLogFile();

private static string GetLogFile()
{
    var fileTarget = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("file-target");
    var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
    string fileName = fileTarget.FileName.Render(logEventInfo);
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        throw new Exception("Log file does not exist.");
    return fileName;
}
```

I'm now trying to unit test some code which will require the `getLogFile` variable to be set. I'd like to mock this in some way as I'd like to use specific log data for my test but am not sure how to go about it. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of trying to mock a private field, use .NET Core's logging (or any other logging library like Serilog, NLog) and either mock the `ILogger` interface or add test sinks instead of actual sinks

Comment: BTW you'll have to use `ILogger` anyway - all .NET Core packages that require logging expect it to be there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to mock NLog log methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918440/is-it-possible-to-mock-nlog-log-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mocking" a `private static` field or method is not really possible.
To have this kind of method as a private member of another class smells like a violation of Single Responsibility Principle.

You should probably refactor this behavior to a separate class and hide it behind an interface. I'm not entirely sure what the NLog Code does, but what your method really seem to do is not providing the log file, but the name of the log file (you return `fileName`) So this is how it could look like:

```
public interface ILogFileNameProvider 
{
    string GetLogFileName();
}

public class DefaultLogFileNameProvider : ILogFileNameProvider
{
    public string GetLogFileName()
    {
         // your code ommitted
    }
}
```

It's just an example on how you can handle it. The naming/structure and how you use it is up to you.
This interface can then be injected in the using class that currently has the private methods. This dependency/call can be mocked.

Usage with constructor injection:

```
public class LogFileNameUsingService
{
    private readonly ILogFileNameProvider _logFileNameProvider;

    public LogFileNameUsingService(ILogFileNameProvider logFileNameProvider)
    {
        _logFileNameProvider = logFileNameProvider;
    }
}
```

Test with [xUnit](https://xunit.net/) and [AutoMocker](https://github.com/moq/Moq.AutoMocker) as example:

```
[Theory]
public void TestWithMockedLogFileName()
{
    //Arrange
    var mocker = new AutoMocker();
    var logFileNameProviderMock = mocker.GetMock<ILogFileNameProvider>();
    logFileNameProviderMock.Setup(x => x.GetLogFileName()).Returns("your mocked file name.log");
    var sut = mocker.CreateInstance<LogFileNameUsingService>();
    //Act
    var result = sut.TestedMethodWhichUsesLogFileName();
    //Assert whatever you want to test
}
```

This also allows you swap out the current logic to get a log file later without changing the logic of the existing class.

Comment: Thanks @BloodyMettle. What is `AutoMocker()`?

Comment: @runnerpaul - AutoMocker is an extension to the Moq Framework which simplyfies mocking setup: 
[AutoMock Github repository](https://github.com/moq/Moq.AutoMocker).
It's available as a nuget package as well:
[AutoMock Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq.AutoMock/).